# Selecting an entire row of a minimum element in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I am new to R and I am trying to get the minimum Distance value and the corresponding "Record2_ID" value for every unique "Record1_ID" value for the below dataframe

```
Record1_ID  Record2_ID  Distance
6       10_Bil      0.95337476
6       11_Bla      0.852558044
6       12_Bon      1
6       13_Bra      1
684     78_Lip      0.957437173
684     79_Lip      1
684     80_Liv      0.950852681
684     81_Lun      0.914874347
3065        136_Pri     1
3065        137_Pro     0.895742793
3065        138_Rec     0.895742793
3065        139_Ren     0.934061953
```

I used the function `tapply(x$Distance_Cosine, cosine_dist_type_data$Record1_rowID, min)`, but using `tapply` I am not getting "Record2_rowID" values. Ideally the output should be

```
Record1_ID  Record2_ID  Min_Distance
6       11_Bla      0.852558044
684     81_Lun      0.914874347
3065        137_Pro     0.895742793
```

Can this be done using `sapply` or any other function. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you may use the `base` function `ave`

```
df[df$Distance == ave(df$Distance, df$Record1_ID, FUN = min), ]
#    Record1_ID Record2_ID  Distance
# 2           6     11_Bla 0.8525580
# 8         684     81_Lun 0.9148743
# 10       3065    137_Pro 0.8957428
# 11       3065    138_Rec 0.8957428
```

Comment: Really Elegant Solution. It Works

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(read.table(header = T, text = "
            Record1_ID  Record2_ID  Distance
6       10_Bil      0.95337476
6       11_Bla      0.852558044
6       12_Bon      1
6       13_Bra      1
684     78_Lip      0.957437173
684     79_Lip      1
684     80_Liv      0.950852681
684     81_Lun      0.914874347
3065        136_Pri     1
3065        137_Pro     0.895742793
3065        138_Rec     0.895742793
3065        139_Ren     0.934061953
            "))

df[, Min_Distance := min(Distance), by = Record1_ID]
df[Distance == Min_Distance,]
```

---

Or slightly more straightforward:

```
df[, .SD[Distance == min(Distance)], by=Record1_ID]
```

`.SD` contains the `S`ubset of `D`ata for each group. We just select the rows we want on that subset corresponding to `min(Distance)`.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a dataframe, you want to look at [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html), specifically the ddply function. Not tremendously elegant, but try...

```
min_vals.df <- ddply(.data = df,
                     .variables = "Record1_ID",
                     .fun = function(x){
                         return(x[x$Distance == min(x$Distance),c("Record2_ID","Distance")])
```

Plyr and it's successor, dplyr, are "apply for data frames", iterating through each unique permutation of .variables and performing whatever function you want on the resulting data.

Comment: Yes it is a dataframe

Comment: Then...yes, try the above ;).

Answer (score 1):

or without plyr:

```
blah <- lapply(split(df, df["Record1_ID"]), function(x) x[which.min(x$Distance),])
min_vals.df <- do.call(rbind, blah)
```

#### (edit) a modification to include all min. values (if there are ties)

```
blah <- lapply(split(df, df["Record1_ID"]), function(x) subset(x, Distance==min(Distance)))
min_vals.df <- do.call(rbind, blah)
```

Comment: Lebatsnok - Your solution but for the row number 3065. It gives only one value. It is better if it gives both the values. Thanks

Comment: Right. this is from how which.min works - but I would now prefer the solution wit `ave` (the currently accepted solution). or you could use the edited version above

Answer (score 0):

Or with `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

df %.% group_by(Record1_ID) %.% filter(Distance == min(Distance))
```